# fewer vs less, when concurrently describing countable and uncountable things

Tags: word-usage, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Which is more correct?

> Requested data must be 19 characters or fewer
>
> Requested data must be 19 characters or less

There is a comparison between the actual and expected character counts, which is a countable thing. +1 for *fewer*.

There is another comparison between the actual and expected amount of data, which i use as an uncountable collective noun, "some data". +1 for *less*.

Comment: *Fewer/less* here applies only to the number. The word *data*, and arguably even *characters*, should not affect your choice.

Comment: You need firstly to realise that the 'count nouns take fewer, non-count take less' 'rule' is a rule of thumb (a good one) rather than always mandatory. 'That's one less problem' is far more common and natural-sounding than 'That's one fewer problem'. // The fewer / less here refers to 'characters' in the first instance. // The use of 'be' here is awkward if colloquial; 'consist of' as in 'The teams consist of 10 players or fewer' clarifies agreement to an extent. However, the first point in this comment muddies the waters: ...

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ten+men+or+less%2Cten+men+or+fewer%2C+men+or+less%2Cmen+or+fewer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cten%20men%20or%20less%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20or%20less%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20or%20fewer%3B%2Cc0) would seem to indicate that 'less' may be the more popular choice even when the 'rule' argues against this....

Comment: And [these](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=characters+or+less%2Ccharacters+or+fewer%2Cletters+or+less%2Cletters+or+fewer&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccharacters%20or%20less%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccharacters%20or%20fewer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cletters%20or%20less%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cletters%20or%20fewer%3B%2Cc0) add weight to that argument. One in particular is a very strange graph.